# Reading one more line when parsing CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm using the following code in `PHP` to read a `CSV` file:

```
  $file = fopen("customers.csv", "r");

  while (!feof($file))
  {
    $rr = fgetcsv($file);
    $name = $rr[0];
    $surname = $rr[1];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO customer SET ...';
    ...
    $s->execute();
  }
  fclose($file);
```

The code will insert all the records in the `CSV` file into `customer` table,
but it tries to insert one line more with `NULL` values and fails.

How would you correct the code to insert only the number of lines that are
in the `customers.csv` file?

Comment: Check if `$name` is empty, and don't INSERT if it is

Comment: You could simple use `while(($rr = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)` instead – `fgetcsv` will return `false` when it has reached the end of the file.

Comment: Instead of manual `fgetcsv`ing, use a `SplFileObject` foreach with ::READ_CSV and ::SKIP_EMPTY rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgetcsv` function will encounter `EOF`, but you do not exit the loop immediately.  Instead you process the row of CSV as normal before checking for EOF in the while condition.  Simply add a check for `EOF` immediately after the call to `fgetcsv` (and also in the while loop perhaps).  But you could also do `while (true) {...}`  and then 'exit' the while loop when you encounter `EOF` (or if `$rr` is empty) immediately after `fgetcsv` function.  (Not sure of the php syntax, otherwise I would post exact code, but this logic should work)